# I-search - case sensitive

Tags: isearch, case-folding

windows 10, emacs 26.1

When I use `I-search`, then Emacs ignore case sensitive.

[image]

but I need case sensitive `I-search`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can toggle case sensitivity during incremental search by typing <kbd>M-c</kbd>.

Documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Special-Isearch.html#Special-Isearch).

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>C-s M-c</kbd>

**C-s** for isearch and when in minibuffer type **M-c**